# Switch class with condition

Tags: jquery

I want to switch the class with the condition, but it does not work, tell me please where is the wrong place. The class should
will turn on instantly but turn off after 3 seconds. Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
$(".sm-menu").click(function(menu){
  setTimeout(('.menu_ul').toggleClass('menu_ul-off') menu, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` like this

*The first time you press the button turns on the class immediately, the second time you press the button turns off after three seconds.* you can check for the class by using `hasClass()`

```js
$(".sm-menu").click(function(menu){
  if(!$('.menu_ul').hasClass('menu_ul-off')){
    $('.menu_ul').addClass('menu_ul-off');
  }else{
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.menu_ul').removeClass('menu_ul-off');
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

```css
.menu_ul{
  display : none;
}
.menu_ul-off{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sm-menu">Menu Click<div>

<div class="menu_ul">Menu UL<div>
```

**OR** you can use `delay()` and `.queue()` if you want to add the class then remove the class after 3 seconds on **one click**

```js
$(".sm-menu").click(function(menu){
  $('.menu_ul').addClass("menu_ul-off").delay(3000).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass("menu_ul-off");
    next();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_ul{
  display : none;
}
.menu_ul-off{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sm-menu">Menu Click<div>

<div class="menu_ul">Menu UL<div>
```

Comment: How toggleclass works? until the button is pressed a second time, it will not disable the class. I need to pause for 3 seconds after the second one and then delete the class

Comment: The first time you press the button turns on the class immediately, the second time you press the button turns off after three seconds.

Comment: @HovikGhambaryan If I got your point  you can use `hasClass()` to check for the class .. see updated answer snippet 1

Comment: Everything works great, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that .. Have a great day :-) @HovikGhambaryan .. And don't forget to accept the answer ;)